# Specifying Python version with only `Pipfile.lock`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, pipenv

My question concerns the ability of a `Pipfile.lock` to fully specify an environment created through Pipenv. Below is a minimal, working example of the problem:

I have the following `Pipfile`:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
numpy = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Copying this `Pipfile` and the accompanying up-to-date `Pipfile.lock` to a new directory and running

```
pipenv install
```

there results in a perfect recreation of the environment with

```
pipenv run python
```

spawning a Python 3.6.x shell with a successful `numpy` install.

However, if I only copy across the `Pipfile.lock` and run

```
pipenv install --ignore-pipfile
```

Pipenv installs `numpy` as desired, but ignores the Python version requirement, instead using Pyenv's 3.7.0 install.

Note: The `Pipfile.lock` contains

```
"requires": {
        "python_version": "3.6"
```

so it seems to be aware of the version requirement.

Is this expected behaviour from Pipenv? Does it indeed require the presence of the `Pipfile` in addition to the `Pipfile.lock` to fully specify (including Python version) the environment, or is there a command that I am unaware of that could produce the behaviour I am looking for?

Comment: It may be a bug, but if you're looking for a way to do `pipenv install` without it changing anything from the lockfile, there's `pipenv install --deploy`

Comment: It seems that the `--deploy` flag requires the presence of a `Pipfile`, as running it without, even with the `--ignore-pipfile` flag, results in `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'` due to the line: `self._name = self.pipfile_location.split(os.sep)[-2]`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot to mention you need both, but it will just read them both, no freezing or whatever

Comment: @Nick-T Do you experience the same behaviour on your machine? I installed Pipenv through brew on MacOS, the Python 3.6 is Anaconda and 3.7 is Pipenv’s installed version. If you have a different setup and it works, I can attribute it to a quirk specific to my installations.